# Use of multiple AND operator in awk for specific pattern match

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want to check columns which don't have certain values and redirect them to another file.
Why is my code not working??

my code

```
awk -F '|' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {
if (  ($2 ~ /FOP/ || $2 !~ /FOP/)  && $4 !~/ABC/ && $5 !~ /^YX.*$/ && $6 !~ /Clone/) print}' file
```

file:

```
|FOP|12345|ABC|YX0937|Clone|
AED|FOP|12345|ABC|aacc|Clone|
AUS|FOP|3446|XXW|tred|Clone|
|POP|3452|ABC|aacc|Clone|
|TOP|1234|KBJ|YX|Client|
```

expected output:

```
AED|FOP|12345|ABC|aacc|Clone|
AUS|FOP|3446|XXW|tred|Clone|
|POP|3452|ABC|aacc|Clone|
```

Basically I want to exclude those records which has specific pattern like :-

```
$2=FOP
$4=ABC 
$5=starts with YX
$6=Clone
```

Comment: `$6 !~ /Clone/` won't match a single record of your data. Also, `($2 ~ /FOP/ || $2 !~ /FOP/)` is useless as it matches everything.

Comment: **Think** about what you're writing - for what input could `($2 ~ /FOP/ || $2 !~ /FOP/)` be false? Consider input of `foo FOP bar` and `foo whatever bar` - which of those 2 lines would result in that condition being false? If you don't know, run `echo 'foo FOP bar' | awk '($2 ~ /FOP/ || $2 !~ /FOP/)'` and `echo 'foo whatever bar' | awk '($2 ~ /FOP/ || $2 !~ /FOP/)'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These requirements:

*exclude those records which has specific pattern like:*

```
$2=FOP
$4=ABC 
$5=starts with YX
$6=Clone
```

translate into this awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {
    OFS=FS="|"
}
!($2=="FOP" || $4=="ABC" || $5~/^XY/ || $6=="Clone")' file
```

Explained:

- `!( ... || ... )` exclude record if any rule matches
- `$2=="FOP"` second field equals `FOP`
- `$5~/^XY/` fifth field starts with `XY`

Now you just got to feed it proper data for testing. Your sample data won't produce a single line since every record has `Clone` in `$6`.

Comment: Yes, this works fine for my requirement, except , I changed the  || operator -> && for a strict match. Thanks James.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you really want to do here, but it seems that you need to work by line.

If so, read your file by line to an array :

```
mapfile -t array_of_your_file < "file"
```

Then work with lines :

```
for line in "${array_of_your_file[@]}" ; do
  if [[ line == *string_to_match* ]]; then
    # do something with this line
  fi
done
```